# Find Element by xpath in selenium (C#) in gmail - contains data

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

I'm looking to open a link (message) in gmail inbox (click on gmail's title -'Your Order has Shipped') to open an email (I'm using selenium with C#).

I'm using:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(.,'Your Order has Shipped')]")
```

and I find element which has: `X=0, Y=0, width = 1366 height = 406,`

Therefor, this 2 lines passed successfully:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(
          By.XPath("//*[contains(.,'Your Order has Shipped')]")));
```

but clicking this element does nothing.

I can't find any div / span that has fixed Id / class name (gmail....),

please advise,

Gil

Answer (score 0):

I just tried:

```
WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[@role='link'][contains(.,'YOURTEXTHERE')]")).Click();
```

It clicked and opened the email I was looking for.

Comment: Hi, 
Got  :"{"Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with"}" for both.

Did someone opened an email in gmail using the title?

Comment: You may have to use the Actions() class then. You can actually have the mouse move to the element and click. I edited my answer

Comment: Hi, 
I tried, but the element still got x=0 y=0, and exception:  {"Offset within element cannot be scrolled into view: (0, 0): [object HTMLDivElement] (34)"}"

Comment: Thanks draw, 
I manage to do so with a list (as describe on my comment below)



IList<IWebElement> ListofMatches = driver.FindElements(By.XPath(".//div[@role='link'][contains(.,'text')]"));

That returns a list of items that one of them is the correct one.
and then I used:
for (int index = 0; index < ListofMatches.Count; index++)
 {
   try
    {
      ListofMatches[index].Click();
      break;
     }
   catch (Exception) { }
 }

For now - it works, but I'm sure that there is a better way to solved it.

Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: Since the XPath is using contains() if more than 1 email has that text you will get a more than 1 result. If you use FindElement it will return the 1st result(the most recent email), if you use FindElements it will find all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can click on elements that are not visible by using Javascript.

```
IJavaScriptExecutor executer = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", elementToClick);
```

Otherwise if it's not visible you could do something like below which should bring it into view before clicking on it.

```
elementToClick.SendKeys(Keys.Home);
Thread.Sleep(100);
elementToClick.Click();
```

Comment: 10x, 
The problem is not that the element is not visible, but the element has x, y, width & height  =0.

I used the previous answer and used:

Comment: IList<IWebElement> ListofMatches = driver.FindElements(By.XPath(".//div[@role='link'][contains(.,'text')]"));

That returns a list of items that one of them is the correct one.
and then I used:
for (int index = 0; index < ListofMatches.Count; index++)
 {
   try
    {
      ListofMatches[index].Click();
      break;
     }
   catch (Exception) { }
 }

For now - it works, but I'm sure that there is a better way to solved it.